# Unable to build a model with Keras Model class

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

> PS: Keras version is 2.4.3

The function below build the VGG16 neural network without the fully connected layers, because I want to get the feature maps only.

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input
import keras.backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

def VGG16(input_tensor=None):
  input_shape = (None, None, 3)

  if input_tensor == None:
    input_tensor = Input(shape=input_shape)
  elif not K.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
    input_tensor = Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)

  vgg = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b1c1')(input_tensor)
  vgg = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b1c2')(vgg)
  vgg = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='b1m')(vgg)

  vgg = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b2c1')(vgg)
  vgg = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b2c2')(vgg)
  vgg = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='b2m')(vgg)

  vgg = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b3c1')(vgg)
  vgg = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b3c2')(vgg)
  vgg = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='b3m')(vgg)

  vgg = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b4c1')(vgg)
  vgg = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b4c2')(vgg)
  vgg = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b4c3')(vgg)
  vgg = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='b4m')(vgg)

  vgg = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b5c1')(vgg)
  vgg = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b5c2')(vgg)
  vgg = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', name='b5c3')(vgg)
  vgg = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='b5m')(vgg)

  return vgg
```

This function receives VGG16 as base layers and connects them with first Conv2D layer `rpn_conv`. This last one is connected to `rpn_cls` and `rpn_reg`

```
def rpn(base_layers):
  rpn_conv = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), padding='same', kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu', name='rpn_conv')(base_layers)
  rpn_cls = Conv2D(9, (1, 1), kernel_initializer='uniform', activation='sigmoid', name='rpn_cls')(rpn_conv)
  rpn_reg = Conv2D(4*9, (1, 1), kernel_initializer='zero', activation='linear', name='rpn_reg')(rpn_conv)

  return [rpn_cls, rpn_reg, rpn_conv]
```

I run the two functions and store the result in `bnn` (as base layers), and `rpn`:

```
bnn = VGG16(Input(shape=(None, None, 3)))
rpn = rpn(bnn)
```

And then I build the model with the Keras `Model` class:

```
model = Model(inputs=Input(shape=(None, None, 3)), outputs=rpn[:2])
```

And I get this Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-8c789d1b6abf> in <module>()
      2 rpn = rpn(bnn)
      3 
----> 4 model = Model(inputs=Input(shape=(None, None, 512)), outputs=rpn[:2])

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/functional.py in _map_graph_network(inputs, outputs)
    929                              'The following previous layers '
    930                              'were accessed without issue: ' +
--> 931                              str(layers_with_complete_input))
    932         for x in nest.flatten(node.outputs):
    933           computable_tensors.add(id(x))

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_19:0", shape=(None, None, None, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "b1c1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Comment: That is because you created two instances of the Input layer, that will not work, you need to create one instance and use it while defining the model and calling the VGG function

Answer (score 4):

When you are building your model with `model = Model(inputs=Input(shape=(None, None, 3)), outputs=rpn[:2])`, you are creating a new `Input` tensor. This disconnects the graph, you have to use the one you feed into `VGG16()`. Try

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(None, None, 3))
bnn = VGG16(input_tensor)
rpn = rpn(bnn)
model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=rpn[:2])
```

Comment: You made the same mistake in the Model call :)

Comment: Haha, my CTRL+V game is lacking today. Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 1):

I think error is here:

```
model = Model(inputs=Input(shape=(None, None, 3)), outputs=rpn[:2])
```

You have to sent an exact variable as inputs parameter.